# EAGLE - VIAS are smaller on the screen than in the actual gerber

Tags: pcb-design, eaglecad, via, gerber

Hi I have upgraded EAGLE to 9.5 and have one quite serious issue. The VIAS are displayed smaller than in the actual gerber file or manufacturing preview. Do you know the option which will force Eagle to display them the same way? I did not have this problem in the 7.5 version

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

## EDIT

As in the @ThePhoton answer, it is the soldermask stop area. It has confused me.
[image]

Comment: Is the preview using the drill or the finalized hole size? (which is smaller than drill)

Comment: @Jeroen3 yes - it is preview if the complete gerber file set. I am using https://www.zofzpcb.com/ viewer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're seeing in the on screen view is the copper pad associated with the via. Even though it is completely flooded with the surrounding copper fill, the tool is still keeping track of that pad and displaying it in the editor.

In the finished board view, you're seeing the solder mask openings of the two vias are overlapping.

If you want to see that in the design view, you can probably turn on the solder mask layer visibility in that view. (But I don't use Eagle, so I can't tell you the exact steps to do that). Normally you'll want to see the solder mask layer in the designer in the final stages of the design process to be sure your silkscreen features are all over solder mask.

Comment: 100% correct answer. Thank you very much :)